# SQL that return count of a value in a selected group and count in other groups

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I have the table below:

```
create table tablex (fileID int, file varchar(10), name varchar(10));
insert into tablex (fileID, file, name) values (1, 'file1' , 'AAA'),(1, 'file1' , 'AAA'),(1, 'file1' , 'AAA'),(2, 'file2' , 'AAA'),(2, 'file2' , 'AAA'),(2, 'file2' , 'AAA'),(1, 'file1' , 'BBB'),(1, 'file1' , 'BBB'),(2, 'file2' , 'BBB'),(2, 'file2' , 'BBB'),(3, 'file3' , 'BBB'),(3, 'file3' , 'BBB'),(1, 'file1' , 'CCC'),(1, 'file1' , 'CCC');

tablex

fileID | file | name
1 | file1 | AAA
1 | file1 | AAA
1 | file1 | AAA
2 | file2 | AAA
2 | file2 | AAA
2 | file2 | AAA
1 | file1 | BBB
1 | file1 | BBB
2 | file2 | BBB
2 | file2 | BBB
3 | file3 | BBB
3 | file3 | BBB
1 | file1 | CCC
1 | file1 | CCC
```

I expect to get only the names that appears in more than one file, and then count the number of occurrences in the file with max id, and also the number of occurrences in the other files. Ex.

AAA - 3 occurrences in file2,  3 occurrences in other files

BBB - 2 occurrences in file3,  4 occurrences in other files

I'm trying to use window function (still learning), but not sure if this approach is the best path to go as i had to add a distinct to make it work

```
select distinct t.name, count(t.name) over (partition by t.name) countAll,
       count(t.name) over (partition by t.name, fileId) countLatestFile,
       count(t.name) over (partition by t.name) - count(t.name) over (partition by t.name, fileId) countOthers
  from tablex t
  join (select name from tablex group by name having count(distinct fileId)  > 1) tdups
   on t.name = tdups.name;
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using the window function `dense_rank`, do it like this:

First `cte` was used to arrange names by rank according to fileID. Get the latest file from each name using cte2 (having max rank).

Then, we join both CTEs to produce the desired result:

```
with cte as (
  select *, dense_rank() over (partition by name order by fileID) rn,
           count(name) over (partition by name) countAll
  from tablex
),
cte2 as (
  select name, max(rn) max_rn
  from cte
  group by name
  having max(rn) > 1
)
select c.name, max(c.countAll) as countAll, max(c.file) as latestFile, count(c.name) as countLatestFile, 
       max(c.countAll) - count(c.name) as countOthers
from cte c
inner join cte2 c2 on c.rn = c2.max_rn and c.name = c2.name
group by c.name
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ea5-j8qR)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the max window function and conditional aggregation as the following:

```
with max_ids as
(
  select *,
    max(fileID) over (partition by name) maxid
  from tablex
)
select name,
       count(*) countAll,
       sum(fileID = maxid) countLatestFile,
       sum(fileID <> maxid) countOthers
from max_ids 
group by name
having count(distinct fileId)  > 1
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ltcH0QB3)

Answer (score 0):

Possible to do without using a window function:

```
select name,
(select max(fileId) 
from tablex
where name=t.name) as max_fileid,
count(case when fileid= (select max(fileId) 
                        from tablex
                        where name=t.name)
            then 1
        end) as count_for_max_fileid,
count(case when fileid != (select max(fileId) 
                        from tablex
                        where name=t.name)
            then 1
        end)as count_for_other
from tablex t
where name in (select name from tablex group by name having count(distinct fileid)>1)
group by name
;

-- result set:
+------+------------+----------------------+-----------------+
| name | max_fileid | count_for_max_fileid | count_for_other |
+------+------------+----------------------+-----------------+
| AAA  |          2 |                    3 |               3 |
| BBB  |          3 |                    2 |               4 |
+------+------------+----------------------+-----------------+
```